# How can I get all the woocommerce api orders

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, api

When I do a get with my postman to

> https://page.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders

It only returns 10 results, and in woocommerce I have 2000 orders
How can I get those 2000 orders?

Comment: If the standard REST API pagination does not work for you then you will need to ask their support or ask in one of their communities, 3rd party plugin dev support is off-topic here

Answer (score 2):

By default, that API endpoint is paged and the amount per_page is set to 10. You can see all the defaults for that endpoint here https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-orders

If this endpoint works like WP_Query then you'll need to set the per_page parameter to -1. Otherwise you'll need to make multiple requests, incrementing the page number each time until you've received all the orders

Comment: So I can't see all the orders in a single result ???
How can I know how many orders I have in total?

Comment: If I do what you say to put% per_page = -1 I get the following: per_page must be between 1 (included) and 100 (included)

Comment: In that case, you'll need to set the page parameter instead and keep making more requests until there are no more to get. It doesn't look like there is a way to get all of them at once from looking at the docs

Comment: It's probably using the default REST API mechanism so you'll have X-WP-Total and X-WP-TotalPages headers that give you hte number of pages too: [REST API Pagination](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/).

Answer (score 0):

this will surely show all orders

```
  enter code here
  const WooCommerceRestApi = require("@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api").default;

const api = new WooCommerceRestApi({
  url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WORDPRESS_SITE_URL,
  consumerKey: process.env.CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumerSecret: process.env.CONSUMER_SECRET,
  version: "wc/v3"
});
export default async function handler(req, res){
  const responseData = {
      success:false,
      orders: []
  }

  const { perPage} = req?.query ?? {};
  try {
      const {data} = await api.get(
          'orders',
          {
              per_page:perPage||100


          }
      );
      responseData.success = true;
      responseData.orders = data;
      res.json( responseData);
  } catch ( error ){
      responseData.error = error.message;
      res.status(500).json(responseData);
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it'll only fetch a single page of 100 orders. OP said they had 2000 (and were hoping to get all orders in a single request anyway, not pages)